# URL pattern for query string parameters Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, url-parameters, query-string, url-pattern

This is my current url path is as `http://localhost:8000/api/projects/abcml/2021`
and in the urls.py page I am passing as `path("api/projects/<str:project_handle>/<int:year>", functionname...)`  and in the view, I accept this parameters with `self.kwargs.get` method.

I want to pass url as this format `http://localhost:8000/api/projects/abcml/?year=2021`
What changes do I need to make in url pattern?

I tried this `path("api/projects/<str:project_handle>/?year=<int:year>` but did not seem correct also in the view page, instead of `self.kwargs.get` I changed it to `self.request.query_params.get` for `year` parameter. That did not work either. Error it throwing is Page not found (404).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is *not* part of the path, and therefore can *not* be matched.

You thus specify as path:

```
path('api/projects/<str:project_handle>/', functionname)
```

In the view, you can access the data with `self.request.GET['year']` and this will return a string or a `KeyError` in cas the year was not provided in the query string.

Comment: Its throwing 'argument of type 'Request' is not iterable'

Comment: @HardikPatil: likely the error is somewhere else, for example by iterating over a request object somehow...

Comment: How to check whether this query parameter year is empty or not in the view ?

Comment: @HardikPatil: `if 'year' in self.request.GET`.

Comment: Yeah also along with that, had to check 'if not' condition inside 'if in' condition. Hey thank you! Btw how did you add code block section in the comment?

Comment: Use two `tilda`s.